# what does "post early returns" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "post early returns" mean in the following passage?

> Election officials were counting the ballots by hand after abandoning the electronic tabulation system that had **posted early returns**, The Associated Press reported Wednesday.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? (Note that _returns_ is a plural noun).

Answer (score 1):

Returns are the results of voting in an election.

> [2. a statement of the votes counted at an election or poll](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/returns)
>
> *Early returns show Bulgaria's opposition party may have won.*
>
> *Officials haven’t finished counting the returns yet.*

And there was an electronic tabulation system that had posted them (and which was abandoned).